# Hosts file, but for directories

Tags: proxy, redirection, hosts-file

I know you can use the hosts file to redirect requests from a certain domain to a different domain (adding `127.0.0.1 google.com` would make all requests from google.com instead go to 127.0.0.1). I want to know if there is a way to do this only on certain directories instead of the whole domain. For example, lets say I only want requests from `google.com/search` to go to `127.0.0.1`, but I want requests to other parts of google to go normally, to the website. Can I do this with a hosts file? If not, can I do it with a proxy? If so, I would like specific directions on how to do it.